# Direct combinatorial proof of three successive entries with ratio $3: 4: 5$ in Pascal's triangle?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Find the smallest value of $n$ such that row $n$ of Pascal's triangle contains three successive entries with the ratio $3:4:5$.

I was able to solve this with algebraic manipulation. We have$${{\binom{n}{k}}\over3} = {{\binom{n}{k+1}}\over4} = {{\binom{n}{k+2}}\over5}$$This can be written as$${{n!}\over{3(n-k)!k!}} = {{n!}\over{4(n-k-1)!(k+1)!}}, \quad {{n!}\over{4(n-k-1)!(k+1)!}} = {{n!}\over{5(n-k-2)!(k+2)!}}$$This can be manipulated to$$4(k + 1) = 3(n - k), \quad 5(k+2) = 4(n - k - 1)$$Simplifying, when we solve for $k$ in both equations:$$k = {{3n - 4}\over7} = {{4n - 14}\over9}$$Now solving for $n$, we get $n = 62$.

**However, I am wondering if there a direct (as possible) combinatorial way to obtain this result as opposed to the algebraic way I demonstrated here.**

Comment: A combinatorial approach doesn't seem that likely to me. I would have gone with your algebraic approach, which is pretty direct.

Comment: If you are looking for increasing arithmetic progressions in Pascal's triangle, then for given $n$ you get a ratio of $\frac n2 -1:\frac n2 :\frac n2+1$ from ${n^2-2 \choose n(n-1)/2-2}:{n^2-2 \choose n(n-1)/2-1}:{n^2-2 \choose n(n-1)/2}$.  In your particular example you want $n=8$.

Comment: This may be related to the inflexion of a normal density curve being at $\pm1$ standard deviation from the mean.